# How to echo something after header tag (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

I want to echo something after header tag in single pages.

I have a filter to add something before content.

```
function add_custom_meta_to_content($content) {   
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();

    if ( $queried_object ) {
        $post_id = $queried_object->ID;
    } 
    $text = get_post_meta($post_id, 'textbox_wporg_meta_key', true);
    if( is_single() ) {
        $content = $text . '' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','add_custom_meta_to_content' );
```

**But Now I want add some data exactly after header tag in single pages by my plugin.**

I don't want to edit theme codes.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309151/apply-the-title-filter-in-post-page-title-but-not-in-menu-title

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally do this with the `the_content` filter. Almost all commercial themes would have a specific hook to insert additional code **after the post title and before the main content**. For instance, the [Generatepress](https://generatepress.com) framework would enable you to hook into the `generate_after_entry_title` action hook and you would output additional code there.